# Adding symbols to dendrogram leaves in R

Tags: r, plot, key, symbols, dendrogram

I would like to add symbols to the leaves of a dendrogram reflecting variable for sites on a dendrogram similar to this:

```
require(graphics)

hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests[1:5,]), "ave")
plot(hc)
plot(hc, hang = -1)

USArrests[1:5,]

           Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape
Alabama      13.2     236       58 21.2
Alaska       10.0     263       48 44.5
Arizona       8.1     294       80 31.0
Arkansas      8.8     190       50 19.5
California    9.0     276       91 40.6
```

[image]

Thanks for any suggestion on how to go about this

SOLUTION
Following Backlin's helpful suggestions I use the following solution

```
require(graphics)

hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests[1:5,]), "ave")

plot(hc, hang = -1, xlab="", sub="")

col.circle=c("yellow", "red")[cut(USArrests$Murder[hc$order], c(8,10,15))]

symbols(1:5, rep(-25, 5), circles=rep(1, 5), add=TRUE, inches=.2,bg=col.circle, xpd=TRUE)

col.square=c("blue", "green")[cut(USArrests$Assault[hc$order], c(100,200,300))]

symbols(1:5, rep(-35, 5), squares=rep(1, 5), add=TRUE, inches=.4,bg=col.square, xpd=TRUE)

legend(3.7,85,legend=c("Murder 8-10","Murder 10-15","Assualt 100-200","Assualt 200-300"),fill=c("yellow","red","blue","green"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is going to be really tough with the traditional means of plotting hclust objects.  One potential option is the `ggdendro` package.  This caught my eye a while back and it looks like it might be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `symbols` function could be used to accomplish this in a somewhat roundabout, but still effective way. It does not support triangles, but has a few other shapes to choose from. In the demonstration below, note the parameter `xpd=TRUE` that allows you to draw outside the plot area, i.e. in the margin.

```
plot(hc, hang = -1, xlab="", sub="")
symbols(1:5, rep(-25, 5), circles=rep(1, 5), add=TRUE, inches=.2,
        bg=rep(c("grey", "red"), c(3,2)), xpd=TRUE)
symbols(1:5, rep(-35, 5), squares=rep(1, 5), add=TRUE, inches=.4,
        bg=rep(c("grey", "red"), c(1,4)), xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

For readability of the example, the y coordinates of the symbols are set to absolute values. If you want to make them relative to the coordinates of the plot use something like the following, where `par("usr")` is a vector with (x-left, x-right, y-bottom, y-top) of the plot area.

```
y = par("usr")[3] - .04 * diff(par("usr")[3:4])
```

The legend can also be plotted with `symbol` and `text`. The idea is the same and you can probably figure it out yourself, even though it is quite fiddly.

Comment: Thanks! Definite wok but I am wondering if there is anyway to automate the process of adding the labels as I have hundreds of leaves?

Comment: Oh yes, most definitely, but you have to formulate your own expressions for it. For example `col=c("grey", "red")[cut(USArrests$Murder[hc$order], c(8,10,15))]` to automate the coloring of the circles. I didn't add that to the answer since I assumed you only wanted to know how to add symbols, and that this was outside the scope of the question